# jQuery not Loading for "Anonymous" Users

Tags: 7, javascript

For Drupal 7, a jQuery will not load for "anonymous" users on any template pages. But when I log in as an administrator it loads. It's similar to this issue: http://drupal.org/node/802432, but nothing I tried has worked. The only way I could get the jQuery to load was by giving the user access to the administration menu, which I do not want to do.

I have the following code in the `preprocess_node` function of the *template.php* file.

```
if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
$node =& $variables['node'];
if ($node->type == 'page') {
  $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive');
   drupal_add_js($path . '/js/jquery.snap.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' 
   => 'header'));
   drupal_add_js($path . '/js/jquery.snap2.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope'
   =>'header'));
  }
}
```

Here is the original JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" 
+((document.location.protocol=="https:")?"https://snapabug.appspot.com":
"http: //www.snapengage.com") + "/snapabug.js' type='text/javascript
'%3E%3C /script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SnapABug.addButton("77777-7777","0","50%", true);
</script>
```

I put the code in two separate JS files (couldn't get it to work in a single file)

jquery.snap.js

```
(function($) {
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" 
+  ((document.location.protocol=="https:")?"https://snapabug.appspot.com":
"http: //www.snapengage.com") + "/snapabug.js' type='text/javascript
'%3E%3C /script%3E"));
})(jQuery);
```

jquery.snap2.js

```
(function($) {
SnapABug.addButton("77777-7777","0","50%", true);
})(jQuery);
```

When I look at the HTML source I see an error for jquery.snap2.js: "Uncaught Reference Error: SnapBug is not defined." The result is the snapabug.js is not loading. This error does not occur on the administrative side and the snapabug.js does load.

Comment: Does your intended file (jquery.snap.js) included in the page. Check your html source, if it is only with jQuery or other js files as well.

Comment: @Shuaib Nawaz I edited above based on your question and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal does not load jQuery if there are no dependency on it.

When `drupal_add_js()` is used once any where, Drupal includes jQuery automatically.

In case of user session, admin menu and overlay are dependent on jQuery so it is added automatically. So i advise you to try your `drupal_add_js()` code in `hook_init` just for try. I am not confirmed if it does not have any effect if it is called in `hook_preprocess`.

Please also check if you `hook_node_preprocess` is working at all?

Comment: I did find the source of the error. There was some old code fragment in the in the *template.php* that I thought I had gotten rid of. Not sure why it worked on the administrative side with this left-over code in there. Not sure if I should leave this question or delete. Someone more experienced on here please advise. Though, Shuaib did help me find the source of the problem so I would like to give credit. Thanks @ShuaibNawaz.

Answer (score 2):

And in Drupal 8 just add `Drupal` js as a dependency to  your theme library

```
- core/drupal
```

Comment: does this still work in later versions of 8 and Drupal 9? In 9 if I use your answer I get this error when I rund `drush updb` :  `(Currently using Unresolved dependency core (Missing)
)` I've also noticed some modules, like Views, use a colon in their dependencies - is the colon the new standard, instead of the slash? e.g. `drupal:filter`

Comment: acrually this is fine - no error if this dependency line is added to libraries.yml of the module. NOT info.yml thank you!

Comment: @therobyouknow glad to hear it helped you after 3 years !!! :) ^_^