# Sticky Footer jQuery not loading for Anonymous

Tags: 7, javascript

I got a sticky footer for Drupal 7 but it does not work on anonymous user. I tried "`drupal_add_js()`" in page.tpl.php and it does not work.

```
(function($){

    function FooterBottom(){
    var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
    var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
    if (vwptHeight > bodyHeight) {
      $('footer').css('position','absolute');
      $('body').css('padding-bottom', footerHeight);
    } else {
      $('footer').css('position','relative');
      $('body').css('padding-bottom', '0');
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    FooterBottom();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
    FooterBottom();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

update Jun24th 2017- adding page.tpl.php / this is a bootstrap sub-theme

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a single Drupal page.
 *
 * The doctype, html, head and body tags are not in this template. Instead they
 * can be found in the html.tpl.php template in this directory.
 *
 * Available variables:
 *
 * General utility variables:
 * - $base_path: The base URL path of the Drupal installation. At the very
 *   least, this will always default to /.
 * - $directory: The directory the template is located in, e.g. modules/system
 *   or themes/bartik.
 * - $is_front: TRUE if the current page is the front page.
 * - $logged_in: TRUE if the user is registered and signed in.
 * - $is_admin: TRUE if the user has permission to access administration pages.
 *
 * Site identity:
 * - $front_page: The URL of the front page. Use this instead of $base_path,
 *   when linking to the front page. This includes the language domain or
 *   prefix.
 * - $logo: The path to the logo image, as defined in theme configuration.
 * - $site_name: The name of the site, empty when display has been disabled
 *   in theme settings.
 * - $site_slogan: The slogan of the site, empty when display has been disabled
 *   in theme settings.
 *
 * Navigation:
 * - $main_menu (array): An array containing the Main menu links for the
 *   site, if they have been configured.
 * - $secondary_menu (array): An array containing the Secondary menu links for
 *   the site, if they have been configured.
 * - $breadcrumb: The breadcrumb trail for the current page.
 *
 * Page content (in order of occurrence in the default page.tpl.php):
 * - $title_prefix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
 *   appears in the template.
 * - $title: The page title, for use in the actual HTML content.
 * - $title_suffix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
 *   the template.
 * - $messages: HTML for status and error messages. Should be displayed
 *   prominently.
 * - $tabs (array): Tabs linking to any sub-pages beneath the current page
 *   (e.g., the view and edit tabs when displaying a node).
 * - $action_links (array): Actions local to the page, such as 'Add menu' on the
 *   menu administration interface.
 * - $feed_icons: A string of all feed icons for the current page.
 * - $node: The node object, if there is an automatically-loaded node
 *   associated with the page, and the node ID is the second argument
 *   in the page's path (e.g. node/12345 and node/12345/revisions, but not
 *   comment/reply/12345).
 *
 * Regions:
 * - $page['help']: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
 * - $page['highlighted']: Items for the highlighted content region.
 * - $page['content']: The main content of the current page.
 * - $page['sidebar_first']: Items for the first sidebar.
 * - $page['sidebar_second']: Items for the second sidebar.
 * - $page['header']: Items for the header region.
 * - $page['footer']: Items for the footer region.
 *
 * @see bootstrap_preprocess_page()
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_page()
 * @see bootstrap_process_page()
 * @see template_process()
 * @see html.tpl.php
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 */
?>
<header id="navbar" role="banner" class="<?php print $navbar_classes; ?>">
<div class="main-nav">
<!-- #top menu -->
          <?php print render($page['header_top']); ?>
<!-- #top menu -->  

  <div class="<?php print $container_class; ?>">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <?php if ($logo): ?>
        <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
          <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
        </a>
      <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
<!-- Add Nav-Menu Section -->
    <div class="navbar-tbmagemenu navbar-collapse collapse"><nav>
          <?php print render($page['nav_menu']); ?>
    </nav></div>
<!-- End Add -->


  </div>
</div>
</header>

<!-- #highlighted -->
      <?php if (!empty($page['highlighted'])): ?>
        <div class="highlighted jumbotron"><?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?></div>
<!-- Add breadcrumb -->
      <?php if (!empty($breadcrumb)): print $breadcrumb; endif;?>
<!--  End adding -->
      <?php endif; ?>
<!-- /#highlighted -->

<div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">
<!--  add main container content div -->
<div class="main-container-content <?php print $container_class; ?>">
  <header role="banner" id="page-header">
    <?php if (!empty($site_slogan)): ?>
      <p class="lead"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
  </header> <!-- /#page-header -->


  <div class="row">

<!-- Sidebar -->
    <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_first']) || !empty($page['nav_sidebarmenu'])): ?>
      <aside class="col-sm-3" role="complementary">
      <div class="region collapse-title"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#region-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> In This Section
        </button></div>
      <div id="region-sidebar" class="collapse in"><?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?></div>
      </aside>
    <?php endif; ?>
<!-- End Sidebar -->

    <section<?php print $content_column_class; ?>>
<!-- Remove breadcrumb
      <?php if (!empty($breadcrumb)): print $breadcrumb; endif;?>
End remove -->
      <a id="main-content"></a>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
        <h1 class="page-header"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($tabs)): ?>
        <?php print render($tabs); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($page['help'])): ?>
        <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($action_links)): ?>
        <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
    </section>

    <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_second'])): ?>
      <aside class="col-sm-3" role="complementary">
        <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
      </aside>  <!-- /#sidebar-second -->
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
<!--  End main container content div -->

</div>
</div>

<?php if (!empty($page['footer'])): ?>
  <footer class="footer <?php print $container_class; ?>">
  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
  </footer>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- add js -->
                 <?php drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme') .'/js/custom.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer'));  ?>
<!-- /add js -->
```

Comment: this might help you: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/jquery-not-loading-for-anonymous-users

Comment: i can't figure out how to put body.height, window.height and footer.outerHeight in hook_preprocess

Comment: in your op, you said that you couldn't add the js with page.tpl.php... so is that not the case anymore and if yes, can you update your question?

Comment: I have tired the drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'them_name') .'/js/js.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer')); in page.tpl.php. I can't figure out how to use the hook_preprocess on my FooterBottom in template.php

Comment: Does it work for logged in users?

Comment: Yes, it works for logged in user.

Comment: gotcha. can you add your page.tpl.php code?

Comment: I just added the sub-theme page.tpl.php code

Comment: Thanks. I think hook_preprocess is the wrong use for this, because it is used to modify theme variables, not add changes to the page directly or add JS. If this JS function is global, you can try to add it to your theme's .info file directly so it loads on every page like so `scripts[] = /js/custom.js` you can read more [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/writing-theme-info-files#scripts)

Comment: That was the first thing I did by adding into the theme.info. Only this script is not working for anonymous and everything else in this custom.js is working fine.

Comment: weird! is the content of the footer showing for anonymous without the jquery styiling?

Comment: Yes, everything in the footer is showing for anonymous.

Comment: I just tested your js code on a fresh drupal install with the js file added to the theme .info and it worked just fine as anonymous user. can you try to add it to the .info again and flush all your caches?

Comment: Did you use it on bootstrap sub-theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61156/discussion-between-cocoskin-and-longboardnode).

Comment: I did use the bootstrap sub-theme, but after your comment I see the jquery element you mentioned do not work for anyonymous like you said... it's difficult for me to help further because I can't duplicate your environment completely. My only other suggestion would be to try to move the document.ready to the top, like so: 
`(function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
         var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
         var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
         etc.
})(jQuery);`