# How do I ensure new dependencies added to the info.yml of an existing enabled module are picked up?

Tags: javascript, 9

I've added

```
dependencies:
 - core/jquery
 - core/drupal
```

to `mymodule.info.yml`

(where `mymodule` is my module name).

How do I ensure Drupal "sees" these new dependencies?

For example, can I clear the cache, `drush cr` ?

Or is there another drush command to run or something else to do?

When does Drupal read the `info.yml` file? When module enabled - yes - but what other times?

I would prefer a command to get it to read that file rather than uninstall my module and reenable my module as this could be inconvenient with regard to config/content needing to be re-setup.

Thank you.

**Background**

I'm working on solving a problem where anonymous users see `Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined` in console, based on a solution  that adds the dependencies I mentioned above: [Anonymous Users See Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined In console.](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio/issues/2967944)

**Potentially related:** [jQuery not Loading for “Anonymous” Users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/jquery-not-loading-for-anonymous-users)

Comment: Are missing another space before the two `-`? There's only one space, right?

Comment: Do you mean there are too many spaces on the line before or after the `-` or do you mean there needs to be an empty line between the 2 dependenices, @leymannx? (thank you for taking the time to look, please let me know your thoughts)

Comment: Before each `-` there seems to be one space too few. There need to be two spaces before each `-`. Simply look in other modules in core to compare.

Comment: +1 Thanks - do you know when, apart from enabling the module, Drupal reads the info.yml file (as per my question)? Also - I notice that some dependencies use a colon, as in `drupal:file` - should I do the same, instead of the slash?

Comment: hook_requirements() has 3 phases : `install` (called while the module is installed), `runtime` (called during regular use of the website), `update` (called while the update.php is being executed). I am not sure but I guess running an update or cron might read the requirements in .info files.

Comment: +1 thank you it happens in update - e.g. when running `drush updb`  - i.e. Drupal reads the module info.yml file then. I know this because I got an error about the dependency I used - `Currently using Unresolved dependency core (Missing)` - so that tells me it looked at my info.yml file while the dependency I added there, `core/drupal`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing dependencies to modules with dependency to libraries. Your code adds a PHP module dependency to `core/jquery`, and I don't know any module of this name.

(When in module.info.yml)
If you want to add a (JS or CSS) library dependency, use the `libraries:` key and not `dependencies:`

(When in module.libraries.yml)
Remember that just defining a library does not automatically load it, you still must add it in module.info (or load it dynamically)